# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string - laravel - upload file

Tags: laravel, file-upload, eloquent, upload

hello i want to upload image via laravel. but i got this Error message:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string
```

i put my code below and will appreciate you for solve this problem.

i searched the problem and most of people said i should add enctype="multipart/form-data" but also i do have this attribute in my form.

here is my code

my Product.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{url('/addProduct')}}" mathod="POST" class="forms-sample" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="name of product">
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">description</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="description of product"></textarea>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="price of product">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">discount price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="discountprice" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="discount price of product">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputUsername1">quantity</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="quantity of product">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">category</label>
                      <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="category" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                            @foreach($category as $cat)
                            <option value="{{$cat->category_name}}">{{$cat->category_name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>

                        <input type="file" name="image" class="file-upload-default">

                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Submit</input>
                      <button class="btn btn-dark">Cancel</button>
                    </form>
```

my Controller:

```
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Product;
.
.
.
public function addProduct(Request $request)
    {
        $product=new product;

        $product->title=$request->title;
        $product->description=$request->description;
        $product->category=$request->category;
        $product->quantity=$request->quantity;
        $product->price=$request->price;
        $product->discount_price=$request->discountprice;

        $image= $request->image;
        $imagename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move('product', $imagename);

        // $product->image=$imagename;

        $product-> save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'محصول با موفقیت افزوده شد');
    }
```

my web.php file:

```
route::get('/addProduct', [AdminController::class, 'addProduct']);
```

i can't findout what is wrong with my code because when i check with other tutorials there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use file() method

```
    $image= $request->file('image');
    $imagename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move('product', $imagename);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but now i get this error:

Comment: Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Comment: can you dd($image) to check what you get

Comment: sorry i dont get it what do you mean?

Comment: He meant to write `dd($image);` after `$image= $request->file('image');`

Comment: @MatinRajabi  $image= $request->file('image');   dd($image);

Comment: aha. i just get null

Comment: there is a problem you should not get the null...

Comment: <input type="file"  accept="image/*"  name="image" class="file-upload-default">   try this the check you get null or not

Comment: yeah i try it and it's still null

Comment: you use this $image= $request->file('image');  or this $image= $request->image;  ?

Comment: share your latest code in question also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is this line

```
<form action="{{url('/addProduct')}}" mathod="POST" class="forms-sample" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

change `mathod` to `method`.

And change `get` to `post` in your route as well

```
Route::post('/addProduct', [AdminController::class, 'addProduct']);
```

And then you can re-test ! I hope it works .